# vba value changes multiple values

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Completely lost newbie here.

I am trying to get multiple, specific field values to change based on input from another field. I keep getting Out of Stack Space errors. Here is the code I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("D2").Value = "Small" Then
        Range("A7").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A8").Value = "No"
        Range("A11").Value = "No"
        Range("A14").Value = "No"
        Range("A15").Value = "No"
        Range("A16").Value = "No"
        Range("A17").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A18").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A19").Value = "No"
        Range("A20").Value = "No"
        Range("A21").Value = "No"
        Range("A22").Value = "No"
        Range("A23").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A24").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A25").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A26").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A27").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A28").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A29").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A30").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A33").Value = "No"
        Range("A34").Value = "No"
        Range("A35").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A36").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A39").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A40").Value = "No"
        Range("A41").Value = "No"
        Range("A42").Value = "No"
        Range("A43").Value = "No"
        Range("A44").Value = "No"
        Range("A45").Value = "No"
        Range("A46").Value = "No"
        Range("A47").Value = "No"

'Repeated ElseIf Statements for "Medium" & "Large" with different yes/no values

    ElseIf Range("D2").Value = "<Select>" Then
        Range(Rows(7), Rows(47)).Value = "Yes"
   End If
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Range(Rows(7), Rows(47)).Value` looks wrong to me. But is there a reason you are not using formulas for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that your Worksheet_Change event is being fired each time that your code is making a change which will be causing further recursion.  In your code, tell Excel not to fire the Worksheet_Change event while you make your updates:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("D2").Value = "Small" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("A7").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A8").Value = "No"
        Range("A11").Value = "No"       
    '
    ' the rest of your update code
    '
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are the best! Thanks sooo much!

Answer (score 1):

Your Worksheet_Change routine is recursively triggering itself.

Here's the simplest fix to that:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static IsActive as boolean
    If IsActive then Exit Sub
    IsActive = True
    If Range("D2").Value = "Small" Then
        Range("A7").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A8").Value = "No"
        Range("A11").Value = "No"
        Range("A14").Value = "No"
        Range("A15").Value = "No"
        Range("A16").Value = "No"
        Range("A17").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A18").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A19").Value = "No"
        Range("A20").Value = "No"
        Range("A21").Value = "No"
        Range("A22").Value = "No"
        Range("A23").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A24").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A25").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A26").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A27").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A28").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A29").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A30").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A33").Value = "No"
        Range("A34").Value = "No"
        Range("A35").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A36").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A39").Value = "Yes"
        Range("A40").Value = "No"
        Range("A41").Value = "No"
        Range("A42").Value = "No"
        Range("A43").Value = "No"
        Range("A44").Value = "No"
        Range("A45").Value = "No"
        Range("A46").Value = "No"
        Range("A47").Value = "No"

'Repeated ElseIf Statements for "Medium" & "Large" with different yes/no values

    ElseIf Range("D2").Value = "<Select>" Then
        Range(Rows(7), Rows(47)).Value = "Yes"
   End If

    '(absolutely MUST execute this line before exiting)
    IsActive = False
End Sub
```